# Git merge strategy different on push and pull

Tags: git, pdf, latex

Using git to track text files (LaTeX) that generate PDFs.  Half the time I want to merge my changes, which will have a new PDF with it that is autogenerated and so it should just overwrite what is on `origin/master`  so when I push I want a merge strategy in my `.gitattributes` of `*.pdf merge=ours`.  However, the other half of the time when I fetch or pull I want to get whatever is on `origin/master`  thus overwriting my own pdf.

Is there a strategy to make a single file (or extension) merge by one strategy for push and another for fetch/pull?  Or perhaps the context of my question suggests a better approach entirely?

Note removing pdfs from the repo means someone who just looks at the GitHub cannot see the pdf but will have to clone it and generate from latex...not ideal either.

**Edit** As @torek points out my vocabulary is off about `git push` which doesn't merge itself but which may refuse my push if there are merge conflicts.  What I mean is that if two branches have diverged but only because of the PDF difference, I don't want my local commit to be halted by default requiring a manual merge (which is confusing to many users of my repos who want to focus on the math/code but don't understand git).  Instead I want to use two default strategies: one when committing and pushing changes (take the local PDF) and one when pulling (take the origin PDF).

Comment: There is no merging at all with `git push`. The `git pull` command consists of running `git fetch`—which is the receive-direction counterpart of `git push`—and then, *separately*, running `git merge`. There is no second merge step when using `git push`.

Comment: As a general rule, Git repositories should contain only source, not generated code / artifacts. The PDF output from LaTeX inputs is a generated artifact. If you wish to have something generate and serve them, that something should not itself be Git, though it might *use* Git to get the latest .tex files. (You can violate this rule, just be aware that you are doing so. :-) )

Comment: @torek I take your point but the PDF is documentation so it fits well as part of the source code IMHO.  As for pushing I mean that if you try `git push` I don't want to get a merge conflict by default, instead I have clear strategy I want it to invoke for push and pull to minimize solving merge conflicts by new less experienced contributors.

Comment: It's worth thinking about this: not only does `git push` not attempt a merge, it doesn't even look to see whether a merge would succeed if it did attempt one. (Which makes sense because the only way to find out if a merge will succeed is to attempt one. :-) ) The difference between `git push` and `git push --force` is that the former requires that the new commit simply extend existing commits, i.e., *you* have to have done the merge yourself, by fetching and merging.

Comment: The entire process is therefore asymmetric: only humans run merge.

Comment: @torek is perfectly right regarding the VCS conventions on code-vs.-artifacts: basically the merge conflict you get comes from the (non-textual) PDF files, but ideally these PDFs should not be committed in the first place! Actually a more idiomatic workflow that you could consider (if you're really interested to have the compiled PDFs "directly browsable from GitHub") would consist in implementing a CI/CD pipeline (e.g. using GitHub Actions) that would build the PDF from each commit, and make them available as "build artifacts".

Comment: Thx @torek, I realize I'm misusing "merge conflict" to mean any reason git push is rejected, not implying that merge has been attempted. I just want a setup where users `git push` always accepts their local `foo.pdf` and `git pull` always to takes the origin `foo.pdf`.  Git may not be the right tool for that, if so, so be it, but it is simple behavior to explain with fewest steps in git or building pdfs.  Hence, my goal. Thx for help.